# Android In-App Billing add items

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am implementing in app billing for my application according to the documentation

- [Download the Sample Application](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#GetSample)
- [Implementing In-app Billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html)

The documentation says you have to add items on developer console

can I add items at run-time on my application start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. There is no API for that, and the documentation, as you know, is clear in that subject.